# Lightning Knowledge in Scratch Orgs not working

Tags: knowledge, scratch-org, lightning-knowledge, scratch-org-definition-file, data-category

We are using the following scratch org definition file:

```
{
  "orgName": "test_de",
  "edition": "Enterprise",
  "country": "US",
  "language": "en_US",
  "features": [
    "ServiceCloud",
    "Knowledge",
    "LightningServiceConsole",
    "RecordTypes"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "lightningExperienceSettings": {
      "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
    },
    "enhancedNotesSettings": {
      "enableEnhancedNotes": true
    },
    "knowledgeSettings": {
      "enableKnowledge": true,
      "enableLightningKnowledge": true,
      "defaultLanguage": "de",
      "languages": {
        "language": [
          {
            "active": false,
            "name": "en_US"
          },
          {
            "active": true,
            "name": "de"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This creates a scratch org with Lightning Knowledge enabled, however, the scratch org is broken in a way that Knowledge articles cannot be used until `Topic` Data Category Group is disabled.

[image]

[image]

It is not a huge issue to disable `Topic` manually after the scratch org is created, but since we are trying to work with `UnlockedPackages` we are unable to run our tests to achieve the code coverage needed to promote the `UnlockedPackage`. Namely, we are unable to create a `Draft` version of a `Published` article (both via code and UI) until `Topic` is disabled.

My question is, what is the correct scratch org definition file to have a functional Lightning Knowledge out of the box? As well, is there a way to remove/disable `Topic` Data Category Group during the creation of a scratch org?

Comment: Does this [KI](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001SH2CQAW)  helps? using "hasSampleData":true  some related [KI](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001YoKwQAK) around Knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @AbhinavThakur. I can confirm that the GACK is gone when I set "hasSampleData": true, however, this creates a Scratch Org where Knowledge Object is named "FAQ__kav", instead of the expected "Knowledge__kav". Do you have any idea if this can be controlled?

Comment: I have posted an answer with details. I will update the thread when I get some input regarding Knowledge Object name issue

Comment: Wow, cool, I was not aware that I was actually talking to a Salesforce employee. Thank you for looking into this. I'm very optimistic now :)

Comment: Have updated the answer please check other KI

Comment: Thanks @AbhinavThakur, I will mark and subscribe to that issue as well.

Comment: Hi @smukov you can give a try to other edition scratch org to see if meets your use case.However , I believe there would be limitations around.

Comment: Hi @AbhinavThakur, we tried it already but we were not successful. In "Professional" and "Group" we receive the following error when trying to create the scratch org with "Knowledge" feature: `The request to create a scratch org failed with error code: C-9998`. The "Developer" edition also fails to be created with the following error: `Failed to deploy settings to scratch org.`

Answer (score 1):

Issue

Internal server error is observed when accessing Default Data Category Visibility or accessing topic under Data Categories.

Though this [KI](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001SH2CQAW) suggest this is Fixed with earlier workaround for new orgs as   **signup a scratch org using** **"hasSampleData":true**

However on checking things internally got to know that this issue is still affecting  **Enterprise edition** scratch orgs .

This issue has already been identified by concerned team and possibly this will be fixed by the next release patch (Safe harbor).

As @smukov mentioned other issue coming up while using work around that *Knowledge Object is named "FAQ__kav", instead of the expected "Knowledge__kav"* I have reached out to concerned team and I will update this thread with more inputs when I have.

**Update**

Knowledge__kav object is not created on EE scratch orgs this issue also identified as known issue. Check this Known Issue

https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001nd3oQAA

> Summary Knowledge__kav is not getting created when hasSampleData is
> true in project-scratch-def.json
>
> Repro
>
> 1. Authorize a dev hub org to VSCode and then create a scratch org with "hasSampleData": true
> 2. Use the project-scratch-def file which is attached to the investigation
>
> Result: Knowledge object is not present in the object manager

Currently No workaround